# How to load php File into a internal frame/window/div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a website with php database queries. On my Index.html I have my website with a seachbar and I have loaded my phpquery.php into a div.

I want now to type something into the searchbar and let the loaded phpquery.php reload within the div/window/frame. I'm trying to solve it with the GET method, so I just basically have to call up the URL with the search, but even with that it doesn't work.

my index.html:

```
<div>
  <form action="" method = "get">
    <p>
      <input id="suchfeld" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      <select id="sucheid" name="suche">
        <option value="all">Alle Kategorien</option>
        <option value="betreuer">Betreuer</option>
        <option value="thematik">Thematik</option>
        <option value="methodik">Methodik</option>
      </select>

      <input id="subres" type="submit" class="subresclass" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="loader"> </div>  //Trying to load the php file here and let it refresh only there 

<script>
$( "#loader" ).load( "phpquery.php" );

$('#subres').click(function() {
  var term = $('#suchfeld').val();
  $( "#loader" ).load( "phpquery.php?search=" + term + "&suche=all" );
// alert(term);           //term value tester
});
</script>
```

my phpquery.php:

```
<?php
  require("dbconnect.php");
  mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  if ( !empty($_GET) ){
    $befehlpruefung = "SELECT * FROM themen WHERE thema 
      LIKE '%" . $_GET["search"] . "%' OR inhalt 
      LIKE '%" . $_GET["search"] . "%' ORDER BY thematik";

  }else{
    $befehlpruefung = "SELECT * FROM themen";
  } 

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$befehlpruefung);
  while($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
  {
    echo  ""  //echo my DATA  
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried to solve this with .load on click, but it doesn't insert the second time.

> My other try was with to try to implement this partial window with object and iframe but both failed. iframe didn't worked with php and the object import was not responsive to my search when I typed something new in the searchbar

My goal is to insert this PHP File into a partial window of my website, so if I press on search it only refreshes this small window not the whole site.

Be happy to see any advices to bring me forward. Ty beforehand.

**UPDATE**  Thanks, solved it by changing the submit to button and removing the "Enter" Submit with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).keydown(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#subres').click();
return false;
}
});
});
```

Comment: if you echo the query, do you see it the second time?
Also, using the $_GET directly in the query is quite unsafe

Comment: First of all: when a textual resource is supposed to be inserted into a `<div>`, it doesn't matter at all whether it was generated using PHP, some other backend, or is a static file. As for your PHP code, there's a pretty obvious syntax error: `echo  " .$dsatz["inhalt"].  ";` Also, "doesn't work" is not a suitable problem description; you need to check your browser console for errors and report those, verbatim.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry my syntax error came because of false deleting. It was only for showing purpose that my data will be displayed there. Well I have my console opened. That's my problem. First it loads all the data from the database into this Id="loader" div. Then the second time I try to write anything into my searchfield it does nothing only displays the same again and changes the URL(without changing the data).  In Console it say: "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni no the second time it displays the "else version of it" so as if there was no query set.  Yes It's may be unsafe but it's for teaching purpose no important data and my other solutions didn't worked somehow. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need change input type from "submit" to "button" and add value attribute with name of button

```
<input id="subres" type="button" value="send" class="subresclass"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending a form is very similar to clicking a link. Your form's action is blank, which means submitting the form will just load your index.html again. Which loads a blank query into `#loader`.

You need to prevent the form from actually getting sent, since you're handling the click manually. Your code sets up a click handler, but the form is still getting sent. With jQuery, you can `return false;` at the end to tell the browser that the event is fully handled.

I also streamlined everything a bit:

```
<div>
  <form id="searchform" action="phpquery.php" method="get">
    <p>
      <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      <select name="kategorie">
        <option value="all">Alle Kategorien</option>
        <option value="betreuer">Betreuer</option>
        <option value="thematik">Thematik</option>
        <option value="methodik">Methodik</option>
      </select>
      <input id="subres" type="submit" class="subresclass" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $("#searchform");
  var searchURL = $form.attr("action");
  var $result = $("#result");
  $result.load(searchURL);

  $form.submit(function() {
    var query = $form.serialize();
    $result.load(searchURL + "?" + query);
    return false; // don't actually submit form
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the input button, you are submitting the form, thus, the whole page reload, add the event handler to the click function, and prevent the default behavior, like this:

```
<script>
$( "#loader" ).load( "phpquery.php" );

$('#subres').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var term = $('#suchfeld').val();
  $( "#loader" ).load( "phpquery.php?search=" + term + "&suche=all" );
// alert(term);           //term value tester
});
</script>
```